# Run Debug Configuration Formatter error in cucumber-core in IntelliJ 2019.3

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-serenity

I am running cucumber-jvm with Serenity.

I have an error in IDE `Test framework quit unexpectedly` even though the test are successfully ran.

As per findings this is due to incompatible format plugin.

I tried below plugins in Run/Debug configuration;

```
--plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm2SMFormatter
--plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm3SMFormatter
```

As shown below even just `--monochrome` it gives same issue

Versions:
cucumber-core - 4.8.0

[image]

```
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.16.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.26:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.8:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc8:jar:12.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.25.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.1.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-core:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.zipkin.zipkin2:zipkin:jar:2.12.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-context-log4j2:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-spring-web:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-http:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-spring-rabbit:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-kafka-clients:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-httpclient:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-httpasyncclient:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-spring-webmvc:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-servlet:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-jms:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.auth0:java-jwt:jar:3.8.1:compile (optional)
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.8:compile (optional)
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile (optional)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:jar:1.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.56:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.56:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.2:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:2.0.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:2.0.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:2.0.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:2.0.2:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.24.0-GA:test
[INFO] |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:jar:2.0.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:2.0.2:test
[INFO] +- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:jar:2.0.90:test
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.12:test
[INFO] |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.2.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:7.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.0.1:test
[INFO] |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:test
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  +- io.vavr:vavr:jar:0.9.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- io.vavr:vavr-match:jar:0.9.0:test
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] |  +- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-report-resources:jar:2.0.90:test
[INFO] |  +- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-model:jar:2.0.90:test
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.6:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.6:test
[INFO] |  |  \- es.nitaur.markdown:txtmark:jar:0.16:test
[INFO] |  +- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-reports:jar:2.0.90:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-stats:jar:2.0.90:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.2.71:test
[INFO] |  |        +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:jar:1.2.71:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:13.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:test
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:jar:3.141.59:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:jar:3.14.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:jar:3.14.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.72:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:jetty-repacked:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.14.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:4.0.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.14.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.11:test
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:3.14.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:3.14.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-edge-driver:jar:3.14.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:3.14.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:jar:3.14.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-opera-driver:jar:3.14.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:jar:3.14.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.paulhammant:ngwebdriver:jar:1.1.4:test
[INFO] |  +- com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:jar:1.4.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:htmlunit-driver:jar:2.33.0:test
[INFO] |  +- io.appium:java-client:jar:7.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.6:test
[INFO] |  |     +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:test
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.5.7:test
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.0:test
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.3:test
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.2:test
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.10:test
[INFO] |  |  +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.28:test
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:jar:2.6.12:test
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.33:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.33:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:neko-htmlunit:jar:2.33:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.12.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-cssparser:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.4.18.v20190429:test
[INFO] |  |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.18.v20190429:test
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.18.v20190429:test
[INFO] |  |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.18.v20190429:test
[INFO] |  |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.18.v20190429:test
[INFO] |  |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.18.v20190429:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.4.18.v20190429:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.4.18.v20190429:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.8:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.8:test
[INFO] |  +- org.fluentlenium:fluentlenium-core:jar:0.10.2:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jhlabs:filters:jar:2.0.235:test
[INFO] |  +- org.asciidoctor:asciidoctorj:jar:1.5.6:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jruby:jruby-complete:jar:1.7.26:test
[INFO] |  +- org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:jar:4.2:test
[INFO] |  +- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:2.2.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.web:javax.el:jar:2.2.4:test
[INFO] |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:test
[INFO] |  +- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.awaitility:awaitility:jar:4.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.3.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.10.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.google.jimfs:jimfs:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  \- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-all:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-abbreviation:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-admonition:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-anchorlink:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-aside:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-attributes:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-autolink:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     |  \- org.nibor.autolink:autolink:jar:0.6.0:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-definition:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-emoji:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-enumerated-reference:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-escaped-character:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-footnotes:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-gfm-issues:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-gfm-strikethrough:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-gfm-tables:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-gfm-tasklist:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-gfm-users:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-gitlab:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-jekyll-front-matter:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-jekyll-tag:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-media-tags:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     |  \- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-test-util:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-ins:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-xwiki-macros:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-superscript:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-tables:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-toc:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-typographic:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-wikilink:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-yaml-front-matter:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-ext-youtube-embedded:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-formatter:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-html-parser:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-jira-converter:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-pdf-converter:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     |  +- com.openhtmltopdf:openhtmltopdf-core:jar:0.0.1-RC13:test
[INFO] |     |  +- com.openhtmltopdf:openhtmltopdf-pdfbox:jar:0.0.1-RC13:test
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:2.0.8:test
[INFO] |     |  |  |  \- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:2.0.8:test
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:xmpbox:jar:2.0.8:test
[INFO] |     |  |  \- de.rototor.pdfbox:graphics2d:jar:0.12:test
[INFO] |     |  +- com.openhtmltopdf:openhtmltopdf-rtl-support:jar:0.0.1-RC13:test
[INFO] |     |  |  \- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:59.1:test
[INFO] |     |  \- com.openhtmltopdf:openhtmltopdf-jsoup-dom-converter:jar:0.0.1-RC13:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-profile-pegdown:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     +- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-util:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] |     \- com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-youtrack-converter:jar:0.34.30:test
[INFO] +- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber4:jar:1.0.29:test
[INFO] |  +- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay:jar:2.0.90:test
[INFO] |  +- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay-webdriver:jar:2.0.90:test
[INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:jar:4.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:gherkin:jar:5.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:tag-expressions:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-expressions:jar:7.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.cucumber:datatable:jar:1.1.14:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.cucumber:datatable-dependencies:jar:1.1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:datatable-matchers:jar:1.1.14:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.5:test
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-java:jar:4.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:jar:4.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-spring:jar:2.1.12:test
[INFO] \- net.serenity-bdd:serenity-rest-assured:jar:2.0.90:test
[INFO]    +- io.rest-assured:rest-assured:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:1.2.1:test
[INFO]    |  +- io.rest-assured:json-path:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- io.rest-assured:rest-assured-common:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO]    |  \- io.rest-assured:xml-path:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:jar:2.5.7:test
[INFO]    \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:jar:2.5.7:test
```

Comment: Have you tried updating your Cucumber plugin? Also, make sure to use the formatter related to the version of Cucumber you are using (check transitive dependencies from Serenity)

Comment: @Marit In intelliJ i see the `Cucumber for Java` plugin as bundle no version mentioned. I think formatter is deprecated. Instead I used plugin as specified in the question.

Comment: I added `dependency:tree` in case if it helps

Comment: I meant the `--plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm4SMFormatter`; from the dependency tree it looks like serenity is using cucumber 4.8.0

Comment: Does that mean `cucumber 4.8.0` is not compatible. The other doubt was I am using Java 11 here. Does that matter?

Comment: Not compatible with what? I'm saying make sure you are using the Cucumber*Formatter from IntelliJ that matches the version you are using. To check which version of Cucumber supports Java 11, you'd best check with the [Cucumber community](https://cucumber.io/docs/community/get-in-touch/) and also make sure Serenity supports that version.

Comment: @Marit Raised this here https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Cucumber-Open/Which-Cucumber-formatter-plugin-compatibale-with-for-Java-11/m-p/204045#M72 and yet to receive a solution

Comment: Smartbear does not maintain the IntelliJ Cucumber-plugin. Try Jetbrains instead. Also, I see that you are using Serenity so you might have to ask the Serenity community. I see the Cucumber community page now links to Smartbear; it used to link to the Cucumber slack.